# Domain Name, Web Hosting, and E-mail Hosting all on Different servers

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, mx-record

I have a client that is using ENOM for their domain name management, Google Business Apps for their e-mail hosting, and Network Solutions for their Web Hosting. The client purchased their domain name through CompanyX, which manages the domain name for them through ENOM. CompanyX was also hosting their web site up until today.

The client recently wanted to move ONLY their hosting to Network Solutions. So I developed their new site on the Network Solutions servers. When we launched, I asked CompanyX to change the DNS entries for their domain from CompanyX's servers to the DNS servers provided by Network Solutions.

When they did this, the client's e-mail (through Google Biz Apps) stopped working.

My question is why?

According to CompanyX, Network Solutions needs to add MX records on their end...but this does not make much sense to me since MX records (my understanding at least) are configured through ENOM...and since the MX records were already pointing to Google and should not have been changed, then the transition should have been seamless.

Do I have this wrong? Does the web host have to also add MX records somewhere on their end? Can this all be configured through ENOM?

Comment: To my recollection, eNom doesn't host your DNS, they're just a registrar. Your MX records will need to be set up on the new nameservers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers everyone. You've helped me understand this mess a lot better and I finally got it straightened out.

I had CompanyX "un-delegate" the management of the domain away from Network Solutions...so CompanyX is back to being the manager of the domain. After that, they created an A record that points to the Network Solutions IP Address and then everything was back to normal. (At least I think that's what happened).

The reason that I asked for CompanyX to retain management of the domain name is that I could not modify the MX records using the Network Solutions online account management system, and when I called them to discuss the issue they claimed that CompanyX was responsible for the MX records, which ended up being inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify stuff first.
CompanyX is using ENOM API to register domains. So you don't have direct access to ENOM but CompanyX. So you can manage DNS(Including A, CNAME, MX, etc)

In CompanyX's account, change NAMESERVERS to Network Solutions(Your web host).
Then, Network Solution gets ALL requests to that domain - including HTTP, MX(emails), TXT lookups, etc. In other words, Network Solutions becomes authorative nameservers. Then, CompanyX's DNS management page becomes inactive.

In Network Solutions' DNS management page, you need to add MX records to Google Apps. See Google Apps setup instructions to see how. Not a big task.

Alternately you can create 2(www.example.com and example.com) A records IN COMPANYX DNS MANAGEMENT page instead of NS' DNS, pointing to NS's IP addresses. This works but when you create sub domains (say secure.example.com), you need to point secure.example.com to NS's IP manually. When you use NS's DNS, NS can do it automatically.

Also note, once you setup NS for the domain, NS's e-mail accounts won't work. All emails go to Google Apps.

"NS" means Network Solutions.
"CompanyX" means what you meant in your question.
Network solutions is your web host (assumed)
Google Apps is the email host(assumed)

Answer (score 0):

CompanyX has delegated the domain to Network Solutions, who are now managing this domain.

You need to use Network Solutions to set up a MX record.

CompanyX is now merely the registrar, and their only role is to hold the delgation to Network Solutions.